# How can I play Video or Audio on a Jupyter Notebook through VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I'm running a Jupyter Notebook on VS code and trying to display/play a video. From all the other forums, I've seen that using IPython.display is the standard method; however, it isn't working for me.

For example, for Video:

```
from IPython.display import Video
Video('test.mp4')
```

This code generates a video box in the output and I don't have any errors but I can't press play. The same happens when I try playing an Audio file.

I've ensured that the file is in the current folder and I'm using Python 3.8.2 in a virtual environment (venv) and IPython 7.27.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get it to work I did the following:

Uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code and installed the extensions Python, Jupyter and Jupyter Keymap

Installed FFmpeg through Homebrew:

`brew install ffmpeg`

Converted the video codec from "MPEG4" to "H.264":

`ffmpeg -i test.mp4 video.mp4`

Then used the following code to display the video:

```
from IPython.display import Video
Video('video.mp4', width=128, height=128)
```

[image: Video output screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if there's something wrong with your `.mp4` file;
2. Try to reinstall Jupyter extension since your code works in my project:
   [image]

When it comes to use `Video()` to play audio file like `.mp3`, run code cell, there's a window like video but nothing more, no media played.

You may install the module [playsound](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) to play audio like

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound("song.mp3")
```

Comment: You're right! The .mp4 was one of the culprits! I had to convert the codec and worked perfectly after that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Mia. Glad to know your question has been solved. it's kind of you upvoting my answer since it's useful to you.

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow so my reputation is not high enough to upvote yet. I'm sorry!

Comment: @Mia. That's okay, then if you have any problems, you may ask in SO.